# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported with Microsoft.office.interop.word in linux

Tags: .net, linux

I am trying to containerize an .net application, which makes use of Microsoft office word.

I have installed .net5.0 sdk in an linux image and copied the .net application.
Also I have add Microsoft.office.interop.word package to the project.

There are no error on dotnet build, but throws below error while running the application.

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported
```

How can I resolve this?

I am new to .net

Comment: The error is pretty clear. There's not even a Linux version of Word, how do you expect to control it remotely?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a Word document programmatically? You don't need Word for this. The `docx` format introduced in 2007 is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. You could create these directly if you wanted, although everyone uses the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK). Even that is a bit too low level for most people, so higher level libraries have been created, mainly for Excel, like Epplus, ClosedXML, NPOI. If you search NuGet for [docx](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=docx) you'll find a lot of packages

Comment: I have a service which converts pdf to a docx document by making use of Microsoft.office.interop.word in .net and this is exposed as api via FastApi.

I am trying to containerize this application.

Comment: Which means you cheated, because you were using an unlicensed copy of Word to open a PDF document, convert it and save it as a Word document. You need a license for every single end user of Word or Excel - every single user of your API whether anonymous or not. That's one of the reasons nobody uses Office apps in web sites. The other is that they're far too heavy for file processing and don't scale at all. Unless you're extremely careful you could end up with a an increasing number of ghost Word instances in memory until your server crashed

Comment: If you search SO for `convert pdf to word linux` you'll find that most people use either tools like pandoc or document processors like LibreOffice to convert files from the command line. Converting PDF to DOCX is tricky though, because PDF is a print format, not a document format.